# Adding Combobox items from SQL Server using single (and varying) column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

First question here, and forewarning I am very new to programming in general, just trying to figure the basics out.

Basically what I am trying to do is select all items in a specified list from my SQL server, add them to an array and then fill a combobox with that array.

The SQL server structure is as follows:
[Just a representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is3jF.jpg)

The user will select which product they are building when they log in, and then I would like a combobox to be filled with all of the parts that pertain to that item.

The current code sample

```
Public Class frmProduct
    Private Sub frmProduct_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim mycon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection('connection string')
        mycon.Open()
        Using mycon
            Dim prodlist As String = frmMain.cmbProduct.SelectedItem
            Dim cmds As String = "SELECT DISTINCT(Product) FROM [Products] where Product = @prodlist"
            Dim cmde As New SqlCommand(sqlt, mycon)
            cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", prodlist)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = scmd.ExecuteReader
            If dr.HasRows() Then
                cmbFailure.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
            End If
            scmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

The user selects the Product on the login form, and the selected product is carried over to the parts list form.

The error I am currently recieving which is likely the first of many is "Invalid Column Name Product". I thought that the issue might be that the selected product is not carrying over, but I added a label which I am changing the text to be equal to "prodlist" and it accurately changes the label text.

Again I am fresh meat at all of this, so I apologize for any obvious blunders. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The error message is telling you that your 'Products' table has no column named 'Product'.

Comment: Also, your SQL code doesn't make sense even if that column does exist.  Your saying "get all the Product values from the Products table where the Product value is equal to some input".  That means that you can only ever get no result or a single result that is equal to your input.  You talk about products and parts so surely you should have a Products table with a ProductId column as the primary key and then a Parts table with a ProductId column as a foreign key.  You would then get all the PartName or Description or the like values from that Parts table based on productId.

Answer (score 0):

In the image you attached the "Product1, Product2, Product3" are fixed columns?
If are, you have to use these columns in your select statement. This is a bad design but will work.
I assume that's a study exercise, so later, can you enhance your project adding 2 tables, one for products and other for store parts of products.

Answer (score 0):

For information about the code.

```
Private Sub frmProduct_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim mycon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection('connection string')
    Dim cmds As String = "SELECT DISTINCT(Product) FROM [Products] where Product = @prodlist"

    Try 
        ' Most of the DB will having a connection fail, so programmer must set a try catch for it '
        mycon.Open()
        Using mycon
            Dim prodlist As String = [Form].[ComBoBox].SelectedItem
            Dim cmde As New SqlCommand(sqlt, mycon)
            cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", prodlist)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = scmd.ExecuteReader
            If dr.HasRows() Then
                cmbFailure.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
            End If
            scmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ' For more save for this sql will execute successfully, some of programmer will use Transaction with commit '
            ' Microsoft Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h(v=vs.110).aspx '
        End Using
        ' mycon.Close() '
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) ' Exception Message '
        ' [Optional]Release object '
        ' mycon.Close() '
    End Try
End Sub
```

And for your items with it may crash the result, due to scmd was not same as cmde.
Would you please explain [scmd] is stand for?